# How to get the collection ID and then create the subcollection for firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I currently doing an rent app. Then I stuck in create a subcollection for each user. I create a booking details and desire to put it as a subcollection but it failed. I have read through the official documentation, but it provide fews example only. So, how do I create a subcollection?

[image: Firebase console]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very vague. "how do I create a subcollection?" In the console? Via some code? What have you tried? To avoid getting your question close, please add some more details. And, important, please look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would advice to include some code you have tried into your question else it will be flagged and removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to create a collection in the console then on the right side of your screenshot there's a button that says `+ Start collection`. Clicking that will create a 'sub' collection inside the selected document.

If you're asking how to create it in code, it automatic!

See [Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections) to start with and then see the more complete documentation on [Collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections) which says

> You do not need to "create" or "delete" collections. After you create
> the first document in a collection, the collection exists. If you
> delete all of the documents in a collection, it no longer exists.

So the short answer is; creating a document within a collection also creates the collection - in short some pseudo code

```
let myDocRef = db.collection("users").document("my_user_id")
```

will create (when written to) a collection called "users" with a single document "my_user_id"

if you then do this

```
let subCollectionRef = myDocRef.collection("sub_collection").document("doc")
```

will create a hierarchy of

```
users (a collection)
   my_user_id (a document)
      sub_collection (a collection)
         doc (a document)
```

Collections are always paired with documents in even sections

```
collection/document/collection/document
       ------              -----
        pair                pair
```